# How to write a policy for a bucket in cloud template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have prepared a cloud template that creates `AWS::IAM::Role` with `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess` policy.

After the template runs successfully, I execute a python script to create two buckets with prefix `foobar-bucket1` and `foobar-bucket2`.

At the moment this is how the above section of my template looks:

```
Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ssm.amazonaws.com
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
      Path: "/"
```

**Question**

I am wondering if there is a need for the `IAM::Role` created via cloud template to have `AmazonS3FullAccess` in order to create the two buckets?

Is it possible for me to give the role *ONLY* permission to create buckets and then FULLS3 permission *ONLY* on the buckets with prefix `foobar-bucket1` and `foobar-bucket2`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the bucket name is dynamic you cannot create a policy within you cloudformation template with the correct name in it.

In descending order of practicality:

option 1: Create the bucket within your cloudformation template and then create the IAM role accordingly within that same template (see sample below).

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  foobarBucket1:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  foobarBucket2:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: LambdaRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - s3:DeleteObject
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:PutObject
              Resource: !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref foobarBucket1 ]]
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - s3:DeleteObject
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:PutObject
              Resource: !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref foobarBucket2 ]]
```

option 2: Another possibility could be that you incorporate your fixed prefix into a policy and therefore partially restrict access.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foobarbucket1-*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

option 3: use the bucket name as cloudformation parameter and update the existing template with the newly created name.

Comment: I like option 2 the best. If I were to go with that option, should I just remove `- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess` from my template and instead replace it with the snippet you posted for option 2.

Comment: Also, for option 2, what about the role I would need to create the buckets in the first place?

Comment: Yes, you should replace the managed policy with a custom policy, which can reference your name prefix. The bucket does not have to exist at the time you create that role/policy.

Comment: With only delete, get, and put how will I be able to crate the bucket? Won't I need "s3:CreateBucket" Action?

Comment: You should also create one role with "createbucket" rights and assign this separate role to your instance where you run your python script.